# List all one-digit differences from a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector:

```
a<-c(0,0,0,0,1)
```

I would like to list all vectors that different in exactly one digit from `a`.

The desired result would list all 1-digit neighbors of the vector `a`

```
0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,1
0,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to obtain that result? Even the first element differs by two digits.

Comment: Those vectors look like they differ by more than one digit.

Comment: Your edits aren't helping your question become any clearer. Perhaps you should try describing what you want. Are you just looking to create all combinations of four zeroes and one one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
a <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)  # your input vector
m <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), length(a))  # all combinations of 0/1 of length a
temp <- sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) m[,i] == a[i])  # check the differences 
m[rowSums(temp) == (length(a)-1),]  # use the index to subset

#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
#1     0    0    0    0    0
#18    1    0    0    0    1
#19    0    1    0    0    1
#21    0    0    1    0    1
#25    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first format you gave :

```
a<-"00001"
decomp_a<-unlist(strsplit(a,""))

apply(cbind(1:length(decomp_a)),1,
      function(item){decomp_a[item]<-switch(decomp_a[item],"0"="1","1"="0")
                     return(paste0(decomp_a,collapse=""))})

# "10001" "01001" "00101" "00011" "00000"
```